# Data Retrieval from controller to html

Tags: java, html, controller

I want to pull data from controller to Html page. I have uploading file count name as y. I want to show y to Html file (in doughnut-chart) but I can't. I add my controller page like this:

```
modelAndView.addObject("y", getYevmiyeCount);
```

There is no problem here. (I can see `y = 10`) but I can not use this variable in Html page. In Html page I want to pull this data like that:

```
var sayı;
sayı = "${y}";
data: [sayı,20,30,40,50,60]
```